# Sentry expo failed to work as intended locally with either enableNative true or false

Tags: react-native, expo, sentry

Here is my config:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: SENTRY_DSN,
  environment: "app",
  enableNative: true, // I change this
  debug: true,
});
```

When `enableNative` is `true` I get:

> Error: [SentryError: Native Client is not available, can't start on native.]

When `enableNative` is `true` I get:

> WARN  Sentry Logger [warn]: [SdkInfo] Native SDK Info retrieval failed...something could be wrong with your Sentry installation:
> WARN  Sentry Logger [warn]: [SentryError: Native is disabled]
> WARN  Sentry Logger [warn]: Event was skipped as native SDK is not enabled.

How can I test my errors locally?

Answer (score 0):

"Native crash reporting is not available in Expo Go, it is only available in standalone builds or development builds."

In Expo's documentation:
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/